# How to write Position specific score matrix biopython object to the file?

Tags: python-2.7, biopython

I use biopython to calculate Position specific score matrices (PSSM) from my nucleotide alignments. 
http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc255 
So, my script.py is:

```
from Bio import AlignIO
from Bio.Align import AlignInfo

alignment = AlignIO.read("alignment_1.fasta", "fasta")
summary_align = AlignInfo.SummaryInfo(alignment)
consensus = summary_align.dumb_consensus()
my_pssm = summary_align.pos_specific_score_matrix(consensus, chars_to_ignore = ['N', '-'])
```

I wonder is it possible to write  my_pssm object to the file inside of the script? I didn't find any solution in the documentation. Now i can only do:

```
python script.py > text.txt
```

But it doesn't suitable for me (i want use it as batch script).

Answer (score 0):

You could add `print my_pssm` at the end of your script then do as you wish `python script.py > text.txt`

For different sequence you can do this:

```
for fasta in files:
    alignment = AlignIO.read(fasta, "fasta")
    summary_align = AlignInfo.SummaryInfo(alignment)
    consensus = summary_align.dumb_consensus()
    my_pssm = summary_align.pos_specific_score_matrix(consensus, chars_to_ignore = ['N', '-'])
    file_pssm = fasta+"pssm"
    with open(file_pssm) as f:
         f.write(my_pssm)
```

Comment: Thank You, i forget add this string to my code indeed. But my question about another thing. Let's imagine i have a 1000 of different fasta files and for each file i would calculate PSSM and put it to separate file. So my question how to save my_pssm object to a separate file on each loop iteration (i will go via list of my fasta files with `for` operator).

Comment: You would calculate your PSSM  in a loop don't you? Then save each time the PSSM in a file with a different time. I update the answer to include it

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful updates. Yes, certainly. But unfortunately method `write` doesn't work for this object. I have error message "expected a character buffer object".